# Developing google sign-in feature for android with eclipse ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, google-signin

I have read google developers documentation on implementing the Google sign-in on Android but the tutorial is only for Android Studio.

Can someone please tell me how do develop the same using eclipse ADT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these sites may help !

1. [javacodegeeks](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwjL97_aspzHAhXNBI4KHWWaDJo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fexamples.javacodegeeks.com%2Fandroid%2Fandroid-google-plus-login-example%2F&ei=fXzHVYvFFs2JuATltLLQCQ&usg=AFQjCNEc0SnXe9NhYXKT516vT70IPYIDQA&sig2=BELe7oxALKQq0VdvI_IgyQ&bvm=bv.99804247,d.c2E&cad=rja)
2. [androidhive](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCUQFjABahUKEwjL97_aspzHAhXNBI4KHWWaDJo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidhive.info%2F2014%2F02%2Fandroid-login-with-google-plus-account-1%2F&ei=fXzHVYvFFs2JuATltLLQCQ&usg=AFQjCNFhLqMD7ezgHOb15Aw-BlS2w8zilw&sig2=ywpb_MZRPq--iZXWT679mA&bvm=bv.99804247,d.c2E&cad=rja)

Comment: **androidhive** was actually helpful...the previous one was a bit less detailed...